# Ошибка компиляции при виртуальном наследовании с использованием multi_index_container

Tags: c++, ооп, boost

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>

namespace mi = boost::multi_index;


namespace vo {

class Statable {};

class Entity : virtual public Statable {};

} /* namespace vo */

class Statable : virtual public vo::Statable {};

class Entity
    : virtual public vo::Entity
    , public Statable
{
    std::string name_;

public:
    std::string const& name() const { return name_; }

private:
    typedef mi::multi_index_container <
      Entity*
    , mi::indexed_by<mi::hashed_unique<mi::const_mem_fun<Entity, std::string const&, &Entity::name> > >
    > nested_objects_t;

    nested_objects_t nested_objects_;
};
```

Добрый день!
При такой архитектуре кода (это упрощенный пример, естественно), ломается компиляция с ошибкой:

> Error C1001   An internal error has occurred in the compiler

Методом проб и ошибок выявлено, что проблема в строке:

```
mi::hashed_unique<mi::const_mem_fun<Entity, std::string const&, &Entity::name> >
```

Данная проблема возникает только тогда, когда присутствует виртуальное наследование! Т.е. если теперь Entity сделать только наследником от ::Statable (убрать virtual public vo::Entity), а того в свою очередь сделать обычным наследником от vo::Statable (без virtual public), то ошибка пропадет.

Также ошибка пропадет если просто вынести typedef за пределы класса Entity!

Почему это происходит, я не могу понять никак?

P.S.
Пробовал в VS2010, VS2012, VS2015 с различными версиями boost от 1.33 до 1.68

Comment: У вас Entity  наследует  Statable  двумя способами, и виртуально и не виртуально

Comment: @ARHovsepyan там виртуально наследуется `vo::Statable`, а невиртуально `::Statable`

Comment: @VTT ,    class Entity : virtual public Statable {}; и  class Entity
    : virtual public vo::Entity
    , public Statable....

Comment: @ARHovsepyan `Stable` в первом и во втором случае - два разных класса, ка я уже написал выше.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan В первом случае, там где class Entity : virtual public Statable {}; наследование осуществляется внутри директивы namespace vo {} 
А во втором случае в глобальной области видимости

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня эта ошибка воспроизвелась даже в более простом примере. Достаточно наличия виртуального наследования в верхнем классе `Entity` для ее возникновения. Базового класса достаточно одного, любого.

Однако после добавления

```
#pragma pointers_to_members(full_generality)
```

ошибка исчезла. Я не проверял, приводит ли это к полноценной функциональности вашего кода, однако при работе с указателями на члены класса в условиях множественного и виртуального наследования в MSVC++ я бы рекомендовал всегда выставлять эти опции в наиболее "безопасный" вариант.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я почитал документацию на MSDN, по сути, это тоже, что рекомендовал @VTT. Как я понял, эта ошибка привязана исключительно к платформе на которой осуществляется компиляция и выполняй я ее, к примеру, на GCC, не факт что она бы повторилась?

Comment: @WinniSP: Разумеется. Это внутренняя ошибка компилятора. У каждого компилятора они свои )))

Answer (score 1):

Как альтернативный вариант - добавить опцию компилятора [`/vmg`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vmb-vmg-representation-method?view=vs-2017), переключающую режим генерации указателей на члены классов в обобщенный режим.